# Как задать,а потом получить данные из выбранного пункта меню класса QMenu

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator

На QTreeView я задал контекстное меню. Само меню генерируется по запросу с сервера в зависимости от того какой пункт дерева выбран (для папки, что то одно, для конечного элемента - другое). Меню получил. Прицепил сигнал triggered() к своему слоту. А уже в слоте отправил свой сигнал с нужными мне данными. Проблема в том, что нужные мне данные приходят в запросе с сервера. Как в QMenu добавить их, что бы потом при клике на пункте меню получить эти данные. Например в некий Tag или как в случае с QTreeView в ее модель добавляю данный под разные роли, а потом по индексу могу получить эти данные. Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение своего вопроса. Спасибо всезнающему интернету.
При формировании меню использовал сеттер QAction для добавления нужных мне данных. Соединил сигнал triggered со своим слотом

```
QAction *act = new QAction(QIcon(":/ico/"+valueIcon+".ico"),valueText);
act->setData(value);
connect(act, SIGNAL(triggered()),SLOT(menuClicked()));
menu->addAction(act);
```

Ну а в слоте получил данные следующим образом:

```
QAction *action = qobject_cast<QAction*>(sender());
QString datamenu = action->data().toString();
```

Не знаю, на сколько это красиво, но работает как мне нужно.